# angular - dynamically include or remove an interceptor

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, angular-http-interceptors, msal-angular

Is it possible to dynamically include or exclude an interceptor?

For example, I would like to enable Azure AD based SSO in my application using microsoft's ***@azure/msal-angular*** package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular that provides an **interceptor**. However, I intend my application to run in two modes - one with SSO based on msal package provided interceptor and one without (i.e. route authentication to some other backend server instead of azure AD). Therefore, i want to include msal interceptor if SSO mode is selected and i wish to to exclude this interceptor if SSO mode is not selected at run time by a user. How do I implement this dynamically based on what user chooses on login screen? Further details below:

Below is what microsoft provides as a sample application that uses their package for authentication https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-sample-app

***app.module.ts*** of sample application has following way of including ***msal interceptor*** (snippet included). This always routes http to Azure AD for authenticaion. How can I dynamically remove this if my user doesn't want this type of authentication?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    DetailComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Add your msal interceptor code as well.

Comment: Its the official package. We just configure it in main package <<https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular>>

Answer (score 2):

You can add an environment variable flag like `sso` and based on its value add msal providers.

in ***environment.dev.ts***

```
export const ENVIRONMENT = {
   ..........,
   sso: false,
   ..........,
};
```

in ***environment.prod.ts***

```
export const ENVIRONMENT = {
   ..........,
   sso: true,
   ..........,
};
```

in ***app.module.ts***

```
const MSAL_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true },
  { provide: MSAL_INSTANCE, useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory },
  { provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory },
  { provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory },
  MsalService,
  MsalGuard,
  MsalBroadcastService
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ....... ],
  imports: [ ....... ],
  providers: [
    ............,
    ENVIRONMENT.sso ? MSAL_PROVIDERS : [] 
  ],
});
```

Hope it works.